# How to show buttons in a list item on long press

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm trying to mimic the behavior of twitter application. When you long press an item (tweet) four buttons show up on that list item. Any of those buttons can be pressed to take the user to another screen.

Similarly, I have a list like this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,long arg3) {
        startActivityWhenListItemClicked(view);
    }
});
```

The above code works when a list item is clicked.

How can I implement `long-press` and show few buttons on the list item? I would appreciate any tutorial or an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly equal that the `onClickListener()`, but with `onLongClickListener()` implementing `onLongClick()`. I'd go by registering each row for contextual menu, this way:

```
 context.registerForContextMenu(yourView);
```

And then simply implement the contextual menu function overridings.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  menu.setHeaderTitle("My twitter menu");
  menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Remove");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  final int mId = item.getItemId();

  switch (mId) {
    case 0:
      ...        
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work. However, when I long press on a list item the context menu shows up and takes over the screen. However, in twitter app the list item itself changes and shows the actions that can be taken on a tweet.

Comment: Then you shouldn't use a context menu for this. Instead, I'd start a new `Activity` for this, but the base is the same. Instead of registering the item for a contextual menu, create an `Intent`, put some ID inside it to identify the row on which you plan doing some action, and afterwards use `.startActivity(intent)` (probably, even `.startActivityForResult(intent, actionId)` as you want to process the result).

Comment: hmm I'm not clear on how to do this. I would like to show u an image of what I'm trying to achieve but I can't install twitter on the emulator

Comment: here is what I'm targeting. http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SC20120221-184724-550x343.png notice that the list item change when you long press it.

Comment: Wow... I don't know whether this would be the cleanest way but it's a way: you should create a new layout where you would define **both** views, the content (which is what you have now) and the corresponding menu layout. This can be easily done using a `LinearLayout` with `vertical` orientation, and two sub-`LinearLayout`s whose width is `match_parent`. Initially, you'd set the `visibility` of the second one to `GONE`. And what you should simply do is implement that `onLongClickListener` for each row, and when fired, simply set the menu's `LinearLayout` to `VISIBLE`.

Comment: I've accepted your answer since it answered my vague question. I thought it was best for me to ask another question around how to achieve precisely what I'm after. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710562/how-to-load-context-menu-inside-a-listview

Comment: Thanks! If you do, I'll be alert since it's a interesting question. The way I provided is perfectly achievable (you can even make it up a little with an animation, but maybe there's a better way.