# How to load menu inside a list view when a list item is long pressed

Tags: android-listview, android

I'm trying to mimic an action in the Twitter android app. When you long press/swipe a tweet (list item) it looks like this

[image]

This makes it easy for the user to take actions on the list item without leaving the screen. How can I do something similar in my app?

For now I've added a context menu which looks like this (notice that it fades out rest of the app).

[image]

I achieved this by `registerForContextMenu(listView)`

Currently, my list is like this:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        MainActivity.this, myList,
        R.layout.list_items, new String[] {LI_ID,
        LI_NAME, LI_COUNT}, new int[] {
        R.id.li_id, R.id.li_name, R.id.li_count});
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

and my layout is simply like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/li_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/li_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingTop="15dip"
        android:paddingBottom="15dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/li_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#9ed321"
        android:paddingRight="3dip"
        android:paddingLeft="3dip"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked tried an expandable list view ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwE61B56pVQ

Comment: Thats neat. But I'm not after that.

Answer (score 0):

You could just nest another layout in each individual `ListView` item that's initially invisible, then just toggle the visibility of the view on a long click event.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hidden_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Edit" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your activity, just set an `onItemLongClickListener` on your `ListView`, and toggle the
visibility of the `hidden_view`:

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    LinearLayout mView = view.findViewById(R.id.hidden_view);

       switch(mView.getVisibility()){
            case View.VISIBLE:
                mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case View.GONE:
                mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: I read your answer and posted my layout and list adapter. Now i notice you've provided an example. I'll try to implement what you have suggested to see how it works out.

Comment: This seems to be working for me. Though I'm having an issue: When one item has been long pressed and hidden view shown, and then I long press another item, then I want the hidden_view of the first one flipped back. I don't think thats happening at the moment.

Comment: You'll have to add additional house keeping for that, but it's relatively simple.  Just keep a reference to the previous view that was expanded, and hide the view before expanding the next view, then set the global reference to the next view you expand.  Also, since ListView recycles views it might be easier to implement this if you extend your own ArrayAdapter<T> instead of using a SimpleAdapter, so you can control how your public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method functions (i.e. you may have to hide hide_view in a recycled convertView if its visible).